# How to scale and recolor sprite from with script Unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I need to scale a health bar down and change it's color. The current code isn't working and as a beginner of coding I don't know why.

The health bar is a white sprite and will be put as the healthBar variable.

```
public void ChangeHealthBar()//not working
{
    Color red = new Color(249, 0, 0);
    scaleFactor = hurtEnemy.damageToGive / CurrentHealth;
    healthBar.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, 1);
    healthBar.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = red;
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `ChangeHealthBar()` function ?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do instead of trying to scale down your image you could also make it of type `filled` That way you can show only a part of the image by changing [the fillAmount](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image-fillAmount.html) like so:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI; // Required when Using UI elements.

public class Damage : MonoBehaviour
{
public Image healthBar;
public float scaleFactor;
public float currentHealth;
private Color red;

private void Start()
{
    healthBar.type = Image.Type.Filled;
    red = new Color(249, 0, 0);
}

public void ChangeHealthBar()
{
    scaleFactor = hurtEnemy.damageToGive / currentHealth;
    healthBar.fillAmount = scaleFactor;
    healthBar.color = red;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code it should work (I don't have the time now, to test it completely in Unity)
You need to call it after update the current health

```
        float sizeMultiplicator = 1; //to manage the initial size of your bar
        public void ChangeHealthBar(int currentHealth, int maxHealth)
        {
            Color red = new Color(249, 0, 0);
            float percent = (float)currentHealth / maxHealth;
            healthBar.transform.localScale = new Vector3(percent * sizeMultiplicator, 1, 1);
            healthBar.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = red;
        }
```